# JavaScript Browser vs NodeJs compatibility

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

I cannot get why in `Browser` code like this:

```js
var gLet = 5;
alert(window.gLet); // 5 (become a property of the window object)
```

even thought it is old behavior works differently in Node.js:

```js
var gVar = 5;
console.log(global.gVar); // undefined (don't become a property of the global object)
```

But it works like this in Node.js:

```js
gVar = 5;
console.log(global.gVar); // 5 (become a property of the global object)
```

This mean that Node.js do not completely support old behavior? Just try to figure out all of it ...

Comment: Where do you have that second code? Because if it's in a module, then no - it wouldn't work since it's in module scope.

Comment: Second example in NodeJs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each module has its own scope, so when you declare a variable with `var` inside a module, it is scoped there and not globally.

Implicit globals still work as normal. You should activate [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) so you don't create them.

Comment: Do you mean in NodeJs each file is the CommonJs module and the execution of this module looks like this: `(function myModule() { var gVar = 5; console.log(global.gVar); })();` am I right ?

Comment: It is *like* that in so far as the way variable declarations are handled.

Comment: It would be nice if you add this example `(function myModule() { var gVar = 5; console.log(global.gVar); })();` in your answer for other people, not all of them read comments ;)

Comment: @DenisKotov the problem is that it's not correct. That is *not* the code NodeJS is running. It's an illustration that shows something similar, however, each file is treated as a module and  it is *not* running code directly within the global scope.

Comment: @Quentin But at least you can mention this and show example of the code ... because it is not obvious users at least will have underling mechanics

Comment: I gave a clear, single sentence explanation. It doesn't need a misleading code example.

Comment: @Quentin Also is there a way in NodeJs enable ES behavior with ES modules ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
  (function myModule() {
      var gVar = 5;
      global.gVar = gVar;
      console.log(global.gVar);
    })();
```

Here you need to set first gVar in global object after that you can see the output gVar from global.

Comment: I don't see how this is an answer to the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).